# Discussion: Efficient real time chat application in php?

Tags: php, ajax, chat, websocket, livechat

I've been thinking about creating a chat application, but don't know too much about how to create an effective one so I was hoping we could talk about the "best" and most efficient(performance) way to making one.

So the base features are probably seeing each other's messages and a chat log.

So I was considering using codeigniter and ajax to create the view and sending of each message and every time a message is sent, the message is sort in a table for the chat log.  Then I thought, if every time a message is sent a query is sent, the scaling of this app would be horrible, so I was thinking of storing the log on the client's cookie or javascript object and upon leaving the chat, the log is sent and stored in the database.  But then I don't know if this would work or would be extremely bad security wise.

Also, I was reading stuff on stackoverflow about chats and websockets and ran in ajax APE as an effective way to manage sending messages... But I don't really know much about websockets and how to use them etc...

Anyhow, I'm pretty sure I can make a chat application, but a good, effective, scalable one, no...

Any suggestions on the best/most effective way on making a chat application?

Some of u suggested node.js or socket.io.

Since I don't know anything about those two, which one is better?

Also I noticed that in the node.js example that he uses one server for the whole chatroom, does that mean I need a node.js server for every chat/chatroom?

Comment: If you don't want to worry about the infrastructure then you might want to consider a hosted realtime service such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for). We also have in-built support for chat-style functionality through [presence channels](http://pusher.com/docs/presence). I've also compiled a list of [hosted realtime services](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide#hosted-services) if you want to investigate this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are thinking about building this with PHP and AJAX, I highly, highly recommend doing something like this with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) if that's an option for you. It is much more suited for something like this; especially compared to AJAX which uses expensive HTTP requests in relation to Node.js A big benefit of it is that it is incredibly fast at doing many kinds of I/O and is asynchronous. Also, the Node.js process is non-blocking which helps make it even faster.

You should have a look at [this example](http://chat.nodejs.org/) as well. The code was written by the creator of Node.js himself. Also, Node.js can interface with databases so you don't need to use text-based logs or anything.

If you're interested in WebSockets but don't want to deal with catching all of the cross browser quirks, definitely check out [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/). It's a library for working with WebSockets and I've found it to be very good at dealing with all of the different browser versions out there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: hey thx, i'm still wondering about the database part though.  Does each message become stored in the database every time it is sent? I was thinking that this would be a big bottleneck.

Comment: No problem. You don't have to store each message in the database, it's just an option. You'd have to code that functionality yourself if you wanted to do that. I've heard good things about mongodb, couchdb, and redis for working with databases in node.js. The last I heard, mongodb was the fastest but that was a long time ago so I could be completely wrong. It's definitely faster than using mysql or postgresql for what you want to do though...

Comment: However you have to be aware that these databases do not perform very well once the whole dataset does not fit entirely in memory

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a reference to that fact? I've just never heard that before...

Comment: Blog post with performance tests of mongodb in a full memory situation.  http://www.colinhowe.co.uk/2011/02/23/mongodb-performance-for-data-bigger-than-memor/

Comment: Link to chat example is broken.

Answer (score 2):

[node.js](http://nodejs.org) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) seem the most appropriate for this task.

node.js allows to handle many persistent connections with low memory usage, which is quite suitable for handling all chat clients. socket.io is an abstraction over websockets / comet / long-polling that allows to pass messages between the node server and a web browser.

You can still use codeigniter or any other framework for the user interface.

Comment: so u have to use both to make a chat application?

Comment: and which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

If you were really going hard core big, you might want to think about replacing the database for message queues.  Second Life put up their message queue evaluations for in-game messaging.

http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Message_Queue_Evaluation_Notes

Although, chat logs would not likely be persisted on your server like they would with a database.

Comment: what's the advantage of this over node.js or socket.io?

Comment: I don't know that this would be an alternative to node.js or socket.io.  This has to do with how the data is stored, so consider it an alternative to MySQL or a NoSQL database.